# Calculate % from number generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which calculates 8% of the number entered, so for example is in the code below. If you enter "1" in the first box" and "100" in the second box the Total Refund (including 8%) = 108

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    function calcSum(prevVal) {
        var val1 = $('#val1').val();
        var val2 = $('#val2').val();
        var val3 = $('#val3').val();
        var val4 = $('#val4').val();
        this.sum = parseFloat(val1) * parseFloat(val2) + parseFloat(val3) * parseFloat(val4);
        return this.sum;
    }
    var subAmt = $("#sub"),
        taxAmt = $("#tax"),
        totAmt = $("#total");
    $(".val").each(function() {
        var prevVal = this.value / 1,
            self = this;
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            subAmt.val(calcSum.call(self, prevVal));
            totAmt.val(this.sum + this.sum * parseFloat(taxAmt.val() / 100));
            prevVal = self.value; 
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2k1zr59u/3/).

What I would like to do is to calculate 20% of the 8% in the second to the bottom box. So in this example the answer should be 1.60.

Then I would like to show in the total box 106.40 (108 - 1.60).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2k1zr59u/3/

Comment: This would be a much better question if the code where here - not elsewhere, and you told me what precisely you can't do. The maths? Setting the variable? Getting it to display?

Comment: I can do the maths, its both setting the variable and getting it to display

Comment: Are you asking how to multiply in JS?

Comment: Thought it would be easier on a fiddle that posting it, I can edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just extract the tax (the 8%) to a separate variable? Something like this?

```
var taxDelta = this.sum*parseFloat(taxAmt.val()/100);
```

Then you can freely add it to the total:

```
totAmt.val(this.sum + taxDelta);
```

And calculate 20% of it if needed:

```
var addTax = taxDelta * taxAVal;
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried adding your code but I can't get it to work. Can you help? Sorry

Comment: @padders01 I can't provide you with a working JSFiddle at the moment, but here are some tips: put these snippets in your `keyup` handler. The first one will go at the top, the second one will replace your existing `totAmt.val` setter and the third one will go at the bottom. After that, you still need to output the `addTax` variable but I suppose you'll handle it fine.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look

Comment: I received some help and have it working now, thanks